# How to find total power on time in linux using command?

Tags: linux

I have installed Linux on a device. For that device I need to find total power on time. What is the command to find it ?

Comment: What do you mean? Uptime or OS life time usage?

Comment: You can't portably achieve this. In the OS you can find the time since last reboot. For a disk drive you can often query SMART to get the total hours powered on. Neither really represents the question you're asking, though

Comment: `uptime` tracks exactly how much time the device has been running for.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov: I guess there might be a difference as the question asks for "power on time" and `uptime` answer how long the OS has been running (at least as far as I know). Depening on what the device can do before the OS, and whether a reboot should reset the timer, that difference can be significant.

Comment: Tracking uptime between reboots is impossible because the kernel cannot know whether the PC was powered on previously or rebooted. However there could be an EFI variable which tracks that but my knowledge of EFI is extremely limited and superficial. And even then it all must be logged by something.

Answer (score 2):

`uptime` tells you how long the machine has been running *since its boot*, and it gets zeroed after a reboot, so it doesn't solve your issue; unless you find a way to record these values and sum these up, while also having somehow a flag that tells you if the machine has restarted.

You could use `smartctl`.  If `/dev/sdx` is your boot HDD,

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdx | grep Power_On_Hours
```

would give you the total number of hours the drive has been on. This is not the same exact value as the total uptime of the machine, but in most cases it will be a good approximation (exception to this rule is if the HDD gets replaced, or goes into sleep mode for extended periods of time).

Comment: `smartctl` will give the total numbers of hours that the disk device has been on. Not necessarily the same as the computer itself (consider disk replacements, for example).

Comment: True.  Adding a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [uptimed](https://github.com/rpodgorny/uptimed).   It's packaged for Debian (and probably derivatives like Ubuntu, Mint, etc) but I have no idea if it's packaged for other distros or not.

From the debian package description:

> daemon to track uptimes, especially the high ones
>
> The uptime daemon tracks a system's highest uptimes via boot IDs,
> using the system boot time to keep sessions apart from each other.
> It features a console program to display statistics, and can
> send mail if a milestone or a new record is reached.

Sample output from one of my systems:

```
# uprecords 
     #               Uptime | System                                     Boot up
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
     1   147 days, 03:45:55 | Linux 5.10.0-4-amd64      Fri Mar  5 22:27:37 2021
     2    98 days, 00:22:39 | Linux 5.17.0-1-amd64      Fri May  6 16:34:24 2022
     3    74 days, 10:59:58 | Linux 5.14.0-1-amd64      Sat Oct  2 05:49:18 2021
     4    72 days, 04:15:10 | Linux 5.4.0-4-amd64       Tue Mar 10 16:31:51 2020
     5    68 days, 03:41:50 | Linux 5.18.0-4-amd64      Fri Aug 26 12:59:09 2022
     6    64 days, 19:23:26 | Linux 4.19.0-3-amd64      Mon Mar 11 00:46:53 2019
     7    64 days, 13:00:30 | Linux 5.16.0-3-amd64      Thu Mar  3 03:25:00 2022
     8    53 days, 01:00:14 | Linux 5.2.0-2-amd64       Thu Sep 12 19:28:59 2019
     9    51 days, 02:19:55 | Linux 5.10.0-1-amd64      Wed Jan 13 15:26:20 2021
    10    48 days, 05:35:56 | Linux 5.6.0-1-amd64       Thu May 21 19:47:35 2020
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
->  31     9 days, 09:25:44 | Linux 6.0.0-2-amd64       Wed Nov  2 18:01:34 2022
----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------
1up in     0 days, 21:21:34 | at                        Sun Nov 13 00:48:51 2022
t10 in    38 days, 20:10:13 | at                        Tue Dec 20 23:37:30 2022
no1 in   137 days, 18:20:12 | at                        Wed Mar 29 21:47:29 2023
    up  1372 days, 09:11:43 | since                     Wed Feb  6 20:29:05 2019
  down     1 day , 21:46:30 | since                     Wed Feb  6 20:29:05 2019
   %up               99.861 | since                     Wed Feb  6 20:29:05 2019
```

It only starts keeping track of uptimes from the time it was installed - so, obviously, it can't tell you anything about uptime from before then.

Also note that system uptime is **not** exactly the same as "power on time".  It'll be very close, but the time between powering on the machine and the kernel booting will not be counted...this could be anywhere from 20 or 30 seconds per boot to several minutes per boot, depending on how long it takes for your system to do its power-on tests and boot the kernel.

Comment: OP asked for _total_ poweron time. I'd infer from that, that they want the total time over multiple power cycles

Comment: @roaima yes, look for the `up` line in the stats block at the end.  e.g. `up  1372 days, 09:11:43 | since ... 2019` - that's a cumulative total since I built this machine and installed uptimed in Feb 2019.   As I noted, that's total uptime, not exactly the same as total power-on time but very close - as close as it's possible to get, probably.